# R SEM error "Incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

```
#Loehlin problem 2.5 
obs.var2.5 = c('Ach1',  'Ach2',  'Amb1',  'Amb2',  'Amb3')
R.prob2.5 = matrix(c(
1.00 ,  .60  , .30,  .20,   .20,                                               
.60,  1.00,   .20,   .30,   .10,                                                
.30,   .20,  1.00,   .70,   .60 ,                                               
.20,   .30,   .70,  1.00,   .50,                                                
.20,   .10,   .60,  .50,  1.00), ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)    

#correlated factors structure (ambition <-> Achievement) 
model2.5=matrix(c(
'Ambit ->  Amb1',      'a', NA,
'Ambit -> Amb2' ,      'b', NA,
'Ambit -> Amb3' ,      'c', NA,
'Achieve -> Ach1',     'd', NA,
'Achieve -> Ach2',     'e', NA,
'Ambit <-> Achieve',   'f', NA,
'Amb1 <-> Amb1' ,      'u', NA,
'Amb2 <-> Amb2' ,      'v', NA,
'Amb3 <-> Amb3' ,      'w', NA,
'Ach1 <-> Ach1' ,      'x', NA,
'Ach2 <-> Ach2' ,      'y', NA,
'Achieve <-> Achieve',  NA, 1,
'Ambit <-> Ambit',      NA, 1),
ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

sem2.5= sem(model2.5,R.prob2.5,60, obs.var2.5)
summary(sem2.5,digits=3)
```

**** From http://personality-project.org/r/r.sem.html

I've tried to simply recreate the results there by simply copy/pasting the code as-is into a jupyter notebook and running the code block by block.

The code all runs just fine until I try to re-create the model:

ie: sem2.5= sem(model2.5,R.prob2.5,60, obs.var2.5)

And I keep getting this error:

---

```
Error in data[, obs.variables]: incorrect number of dimensions
Traceback:

1. sem(model2.5, R.prob2.5, 60, obs.var2.5)
2. sem.semmod(model2.5, R.prob2.5, 60, obs.var2.5)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

What on earth am I missing here? After much mucking about with package dependencies and version controls, I feel I am simply going cross-eyed here with the answer staring me in the face.

What do I need to do to recreate this model as published?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in that document.  You need to name the variables.

```
rownames(R.prob2.5) <-  colnames(R.prob2.5 ) <- c('Ach1',  'Ach2',  'Amb1',  'Amb2',  'Amb3’)
sem2.5= sem(model2.5,R.prob2.5,60)
```

That should fix the problem.

(corrected Feb 15th)